# Does meta-data need to be sanitized?

Tags: security, user-meta, sanitization

Is it necessary to escape data when storing it in the user's meta-data?  I'm not sure if WP does this automatically, or if it is even necessary.  Also, if it is necessary, should I use mysql_real_escape_string via sanatize_meta?

I'm storing a URL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a good practice to sanitize input and escape output. It's important to use the correct function, though, so that you don't inadvertently mess up your data.

Since it's for a URL, use [`esc_url_raw()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url_raw/) (it is specifically for db usage).

(Note: it may seem odd using a function with the "esc_" stem for sanitizing, since I just stated sanitize input, escape output, but this particular function specifically the deprecated [`sanitize_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_url/) function.)